# Does ThinkingSphinx support offsetting search results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I've been digging through ThinkingSphinx docs looking for a way to pass an offset into a query. Sphinx itself supports this functionality

```
function SetLimits ( $offset, $limit, $max_matches=1000, $cutoff=0 )
```

but ThinkingSphinx docs omit it.
If TS does not support it, is there a workaround? Perhaps using SphinxQL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: btw, there is a dedicated thinking Sphinx group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/thinking-sphinx that might be a better place to post a feature request, to allow arbitary offsets.

Answer (score 1):

Seems can do it indirectly via :page and :per_page.

http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/searching.html#pagination

Comment: My understanding is that this approach it would require two queries which is less than ideal. Seems strange of TS not to support this common Sphinx functionality. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was easy. I don't know how I missed it the first time around but digging through the source I found out that ThinkingSphinx takes an 'offset' option. I'd say it's worth documenting.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly specify the offset and limit like below

```
ThinkingSphinx.search(keyword, :offset => 0, :limit => 5)
```